# How to timeout subprocess in Ruby

Tags: ruby, timeout

I want to test that a process is working so I run:

```
cmd = "my unix command"
results = `#{cmd}`
```

How can I add a timeout to the command so that if it takes more than x seconds I can assume that it is not working?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ruby ships witrh the [Timeout module](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/timeout/rdoc/Timeout.html).

```
require 'timeout'
res = ""
status = Timeout::timeout(5) {res = `#{cmd}`} rescue Timeout::Error

# a bit of experimenting:

res = nil
status = Timeout::timeout(1) {res = `sleep 2`} rescue Timeout::Error 
p res    # nil
p status # Timeout::Error

res = nil
status = Timeout::timeout(3) {res = `sleep 2`} rescue Timeout::Error 
p res    # ""
p status # ""
```

Comment: If you need to do something in the event of a timeout, make sure to rescue `Timeout::Error`.

Comment: Yes. I should have mentioned it.

Comment: Make sure you kill the shell process, if you start it inside timeout block. Because it keeps running. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8292031/ruby-timeouts-and-system-commands

Answer (score 1):

Put it in a thread, have another thread sleep for x seconds then kill the first one if it's not done yet.

```
process_thread = Thread.new do
  `sleep 6` # the command you want to run
end

timeout_thread = Thread.new do
  sleep 4   # the timeout
  if process_thread.alive?
    process_thread.kill
    $stderr.puts "Timeout"
  end
end

process_thread.join
timeout_thread.kill
```

steenslag's is nicer though :) This is the low-tech route.

Answer (score 0):

Much simpler way with thread:

```
p = Thread.new{ 
   #exec here
}
if p.join( period_in_seconds ).nil? then
   #here thread p is still working
   p.kill
else
   #here thread p completed before 'period_in_seconds' 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

One caveat to the previous answers, if the child process is using `sudo`, then you cannot kill the child, and you will create zombie processes.

You will need to periodically run `Process::waitpid(-1, Process::WNOHANG)` to collect the exit status for the children and clean up the process tables (thus cleaning up the zombies).