# Send SIGINT using Ruby on Windows

Tags: ruby, windows, process, signals

For the purpose of a challenge over on [PPCG.SE](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) I want to run programs (submissions) with a strict time limit. In order for those submissions not to waste their precious time with I/O, I want to run the following scheme:

- Submissions do their computation in an infinite loop (as far as they get) and register a signal handler.
- After 10 minutes `SIGINT` is sent, and they have one second to produce whatever output is necessary.
- `SIGKILL` is sent to terminate the submission for good.

However, submissions *should* have the option not to register a signal handler and just produce output in their own time.

I will run the submissions on Windows 8 and wanted to use Ruby to orchestrate this. However, I'm running into some trouble. I thought I'd be able to do this:

```
solver = IO.popen(solver_command, 'r+')
sleep(10*60)
Process.kill('INT', solver.pid)
sleep(1)
Process.kill('KILL', solver.pid)
puts solver.read
solver.close
```

However, the moment I send `SIGINT`, not only the submission process but the controlling Ruby process immediately aborts, too! Even worse, if I do this in PowerShell, PowerShell also shuts down.

A simple Ruby "submission" to reproduce this:

```
puts "My result"
$stdout.flush
next while true
```

What am I doing wrong here? I feel that it's very likely I'm misunderstanding something about processes and signals in general and not Ruby in particular, but I'm definitely missing something.

Comment: To begin with, you do understand that signals aren't native to Windows, right?  Ruby is emulating them somehow.  It sounds like SIGINT is being converted to a control-C or control-break, which affects the entire process group.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682083%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @HarryJohnston Thank you, that did solve the problem with the signals. By using `Process.spawn` I can set `:new_pgroup => true` which creates a new process group. However, now I don't receive anything from the process's STDOUT any more, following [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12202439/1633117).