# Terminate external script from Ruby using Timeout

Tags: ruby, process

I have an external script running in a timeout.

```
def perform(command)
  PTY.spawn(command) do |stdout_stderr, stdin, pid|
    begin
      do_stuff
    rescue Errno::EIO # always thrown when process completes
      do_more_stuff
    ensure
      Process.waitpid2(pid)
    end
  end
end

begin
  Timeout.timeout do
    perform('command_that_may_run_indefinitely')
  end
rescue Timeout::Error
  terminate_script_here
end
```

However, if the timeout times out, it needs to terminate the external script. How can I kill it?

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8292031/ruby-timeouts-and-system-commands

Comment: See that `pid` you're given? Kill it.

Comment: @mahemoff - not quite; I'm using `PTY`, not `` or `Process`.

Comment: @tadman - The question is where. I had simplified this example for StackOverflow; `PTY.spawn` is actually in a separate method, in fact in a separate file. I've updated the question to reflect the difference.

Comment: You'll need to capture that `pid` and make it available to your `rescue` block somehow.

Comment: Thank you Captain Obvious. _How?_